# Styling the thumbnail navigation in jquery royal slider

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the jquery royalslider on [my page](http://www.grouporigin.com/clients/adha/ADHA_AR15/index.html). I have added the thumbnail navigation. How can i style the thumbnail navigation so that the thumbnail container does not have a background color and it comes over the banner image. The banner image should come as the background of the thumbnails container. Please help me with this.

Comment: `.rsOverflow` for the slider is taking a height of `465px`, is it given manually ? or it is applied dynamically?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please check the link again. I donot know from where its getting the value of 465px. I have not applied this value.

Comment: I have added the answer below. Please check. No need to find from where the height is populated.

Comment: sorry, I added .royalSlider{
      width: 1024px;
      height: 465px;   //Change the height from 528px to 465px;
      position: relative;
      direction: ltr;
      background: #eef8fb;
}

Comment: But it does not solve the problem. I want the slider to have the height of 548px and the thumbnails to come over the background images in the slider. The thumbnails now come below the image.

Comment: Did you chage the styling for this class `.rsDefault .rsThumbsHor`, `position:absolute; bottom: 0`. i have mention in my answer.

Comment: Fine, you can give `548px` height to the slider. but `.rsDefault .rsThumbsHor` should have position absolute.

Comment: "<div class="rsOverflow" style="width: 1024px; height: 485px;">" Where is this rsOverflow getting the value 485px; that is the reason a part of the slider is getting cut. It should be 548px the full width. How can i change this rsOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Add below styling in your css,

```
.royalSlider {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. Please check the link again "grouporigin.com/clients/adha/ADHA_AR15/index.html"; Now there is an image background to the thumbnails. I have not given height: 465px; to the .royalslider property. I donot know from where it is getting the value.

Comment: i think now its working fine   you said banner image need to display as background of thumbnail . so it is.

Comment: .rsABlock > div {
  margin-top: 139px !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer, But you need some more work on this, because, if you change your thumbnail, over the slider, then some of the text of the image is hiding, due to the thumb nail image,

Below is the changes required,

```
.royalSlider{
      width: 1024px;
      height: 465px;   //Change the height from 528px to 465px;
      position: relative;
      direction: ltr;
      background: #eef8fb;
}

.rsDefault .rsThumbsHor{
     padding-bottom: 4px; */
     width: 100%;
     height: 68x;
     position: absolute; /* Need to add the styling*/
     bottom: 0; /* Need to add the styling*/
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. Please check the link again "http://www.grouporigin.com/clients/adha/ADHA_AR15/index.html" Now there is an image background to the thumbnails. I have not given height: 465px; to the .royalslider property. I donot know from where it is getting the value.

Comment: Your `#homeslider` is having a background image, which is loading from the css `background: url(../images/home_1.jpg) no-repeat;` from the css file `english.css:50`. @SubhasreeMazumder. Well the given answer will work for you.

Comment: thanks. that was a mistake i did not notice. Thanks alot for your help. Now there is a white background to the thumbnails container box. How do I remove the white background. I want the images to be the background for the thumbnails container

Comment: "grouporigin.com/clients/adha/ADHA_AR15/index.html" and a part of the slider is also getting covered by the thumbnails container.

Comment: i didn't understand @SubhasreeMazumder, please explain it again your need.

Comment: "<div class="rsOverflow" style="width: 1024px; height: 485px;">" Where is this rsOverflow getting the value 485px; that is the reason a part of the slider is getting cut. It should be 548px the full width. How can i change this rsOverflow

Comment: How is this <div class="rsOverflow"> getting its value. How can i control this value

Comment: According to youe question, your thumb nail should come on top of the slider image right? To do that, you need to have the thumbnail image containe to be `position:absolute`, which is present in my answer. And the parent should be in `position: relative` which is already having in your CSS. Since your parent `div` with class name `.royalSlider` is having `height: 528px`. the thumb nail is appearing at the bottom, i.e `below to the slider image`. Hence it needs to be change from `528px to 465px`. So that it will align on top of the slider image.

Comment: No need to bothered about that height @SubhasreeMazumder, you can't able to find out that, One thing you can do is, increase the height for the same `div`. I mean to say, in your css file, just mention `.rsOverflow{height: 528px !important.}` it will consider from your css, not from the calculated one.

Comment: it worked perfect. Just what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. I am not so good at editing plugins

Comment: I think you have removed the thumbnail images @SubhasreeMazumder